# converting osg format to 3ds or .obj?

Tags: 3d-model

I have a 3D model of a car in both osg and ive format , is it possible to convert it to .obj or 3ds format ? I'm using a tool that could only load .3ds and .obj format. the tool is processing.js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

osg and ive are the native ASCII and binary formats for OpenSceneGraph versions below 3.0 (3.0+ can still read/write osg and ive fine, but they're being phased out in favor of osgt and osgb) - see http://www.openscenegraph.com

Grab the OpenSceneGraph binaries:
http://openscenegraph.alphapixel.com/osg/downloads/free-openscenegraph-binary-downloads

And use osgconv to convert to obj, eg
osgconv MODEL.osg MODEL.obj

Comment: the binaries link is broken - do you know where the new one might reside?

Comment: Not off-hand, except the old Sketchup to OSG exporter plugin has an old version of OSG binaries embedded (2.85, current stable is 3.4), you can download it from Github: https://github.com/rpavlik/sketchupToOSG

Comment: For newcomers to this page, AlphaPixel still hosts the binaries, but the path has changed: http://downloads.alphapixel.org/