# How to convert osgjs format to obj or similar formats?

Tags: openscenegraph, wavefront, 3d-model

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990094/converting-osg-format-to-3ds-or-obj) deals with how to convert `.osg` to `.obj` but I am using the WebGL version. The `osgconv` cant handle the `.osgjs` extention. I cannot find any tools with regular search.

Typing `osgconv model.osgjs model.obj` doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The osgjs plugin is intended only for exporting osg scenes towards osgjs and as such supports only writing, not reading.
See [implementation here](https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph/blob/master/src/osgPlugins/osgjs/ReaderWriterJSON.cpp#L230).

Comment: Is there any way to extract back the model files? I can see a `.fbx` written inside the `.osgjs` which looks like a `.json` file to me.

Comment: Files .osgjs are indeed json, and are intended for the osgjs library which is a porting of osg for webgl (a completely separate project). As the plugin is write only, there is no automatic way to covert the models back through osgconv. The .fbx reference you see is probably just referring to some names of the original file converted to osgjs?